# Will you be having rubber or wax with your peroxide? (hybrid engine fuel tradeoffs)

Tags: fuel, engine-design, launch-vehicle, hybrid-rocket

[Hybrid engines offer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-propellant_rocket#Properties) some practical advantages and some budgetary ones that can offset lower ISP, including potentially safer solid fuel to store and non cryogenic storage of some oxidizers like hydrogen peroxide.

**Question:** If one chose concentrated (and potentially chemically stabilized) hydrogen peroxide as a comparatively convenient liquid oxidizer to store, and considered both wax-like and rubber-like solid fuels, what would be the main advantages and disadvantages of each for a modest few-cubesats-to-LEO-capable launch vehicle's first stage engine?

**Besides differences in Isp which can in both cases be addressed with additives**, what are *other* factors and tradeoffs that should be considered when choosing between the two? Just for example do things like ease of throttling and/or starting differ? Is cokikng more of a problem for one than the other? Doe the differences in mechanical and thermal properties lead to specific design challenges?

Comment: related wax questions, if there are some rubber questions please feel free to add them: [Why NASA's sudden renewed (apparently) interest in Wax hybrid engines? Which property is so attractive now?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21333/12102) and [Does NASA still plan for the Mars Ascent Vehicle to burn wax from the surface to orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33726/12102)

Comment: you could consider embedding a catalyst (obviously no platinum) in the solid fuel structure achieving a pseudo-hypergolic engine/smoother combustion

Comment: @ReubenFarley-Hall sounds fascinating, you can consider asking that as as a new question!