# What is the propellant mass for the Soyuz descent module?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, monopropellant, hydrogen-peroxide

I learned some time ago that the Soyuz capsules use hydrogen peroxide as a monopropellant. I'm trying to use this fact for a chemistry question posed to my students, but I cannot find anywhere how much the descent module holds, just that it uses hydrogen peroxide.

What's the propellant mass for the Soyuz descent capsule or what's its tank capacity?

Comment: other peroxide chemistry goodies [Does the Soyuz spacecraft use chemically stabilized hydrogen peroxide (H₂O₂) to remain ISS-dockable for 200+ days?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31337/12102) and [Will you be having rubber or wax with your peroxide? (hybrid engine fuel tradeoffs)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48907/12102) and [Which fuel cell fuels have been demonstrated in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48399/12102)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Soyuz Crew Operations Manual](https://www.infosondas.com/2017/04/pdf-soyuz-crew-operations-manual-soycomrop-19final/) says the system holds between 29.6 and 31.4 kg of peroxide.

[image]

It also has a nice schematic of the system.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful and timely. Thanks for saving my slides!